# Add a textarea in a SVG file (Put a name upper a svg tshirt)

Tags: html, svg, text

My code is like

```
<svg id="product-svg" data-name="Layer 1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1280">
      <defs/>
      <path id="product-shape" d="M1091.89 706.86c-.73-4-8.21-37.53-8.21-37.53s-4.37-35.14-8.11-48.45-9.46-37.43-9.46-37.43-2-11.33-5.41-16.43-14.87-23.39-24.74-32.23-24.79-15.11-37.91-20.14S970 504.13 967.9 502s-3.57-5.51-5.51-6.32a8.47 8.47 0 0 1-4.21-3.57c-.81-1.46-2.38-4.19-8.4-4.12 0 0-.42 4.68 2.6 6.13s4.68 5.41 5.41 7.49.52 12.27.52 14.45-.42 4.68-2 6-3.85 5.82-19.55 5.41S892 513.18 892 513.18s-27.45-13.31-36.28-21.42-27.55-26.61-27.55-26.61-3.64-4.89-7.07-4a30.67 30.67 0 0 0-7.59 3.85s-5.09-1.66-10.6 2.81S782 479.7 782 479.7l-7.69 2.18-9.77 5.61s-5.41 1.56-8.42 2.5l-31.92 9.88s-7.49.62-9.15 1-9.36 3.33-13 6.76-17.36 12.58-22.46 23-18.92 32.54-24.22 45.43S639.43 613 639.43 613l-8.73 22.35-4.26 8.73s-1 4 .62 5 21.21 23 21.21 23l3-20.27 3.74-3.64s16.53-1.66 24.22-.31 19.75 4 31.81 10.71c0 0 3.12-.1 11.85 18.51 0 0 3 7.28 13.72 16.84 0 0-4.78 41.27-5.61 52.4s-7.17 55.72-8.84 66.23-2.08 11.75-2.08 11.75l-2 62.17s12.27 22.66 22 45.64 25.89 57.28 25.89 57.28l26.16 50.32 15.95 28.9s5.3 10.71 7.49 11.64 5.41 1.87 5.41 1.87.42.83 4.57 1.35 63.63 0 63.63 0l108.62-.47 34.1-.1 1.77-26.72a12.05 12.05 0 0 1-3.53-8.53c-.21-5.72.31-27.55.31-27.55l-1.87-12.06s-.21-6.34-1.14-8.84a168.52 168.52 0 0 0-11.64-22.77s-.52-6.76-1.14-7.8a11 11 0 0 0-1.46-1.87s.21-7.49-.52-9.36-2-6.55-2-6.55l-1.25-9.15.42-35.35 1-13.72s.1-25.47-.62-31.61-.42-17.57-.42-20.9 4.26-19.55 4.26-27.55.73-6.86-.62-18.3 3.74-16.43 3.53-29.73-.73-35.14-.73-35.14 24.85-2.81 36.91-8.32 36.8-10.4 36.8-10.4 2.66.13 1.93-3.82zM714.66 1046.35l-16.86-28.05-1.6-1.6-9.2 47.23s-4.08 15.27-4.44 19-1.42 11.36.89 12.43a24.54 24.54 0 0 0 13.67 3c7.63-.36 10.3-.71 8.52-3.73s-5.63-3.38-5.63-3.38 6.77-3 12.38-3.36 11.36-.18 24.86-7.1c0 0-2.66-5.86-16.16-24.32s-6.43-10.12-6.43-10.12z"/>
      <g id="nameText">
        <circle id="rectText" style="fill:url(#toning);stroke:#f8f5f5;stroke-width:1.6871;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="500" cy="500" r="245">
        </circle>
        
        <text id ="dynamicText" font-stretch="expanded" position="static"x="48%" y="50%"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="400%"></text>
      </g>  
  </svg>
```

Want to resize the text in textarea.As SVG doesn't support textarea then how can it be possible.Please suggest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My aim is to add a textarea upper a tshirt svg so that I can change the size of the text dynamically ,color dynamically.

Comment: if you need a textarea in SVG you will need to put it in an foreignObject. But there are several ways to resize the text so that it fits in a box.

Comment: Please share the other ways to achieve the resize operation. My code as above.

Comment: What's wrong with increasing the font-size? (Also FWIW -  SVG sub-elements don't support the position attribute)

Comment: Be aware that the `<foreignObject>` solution will only work in a browser. So If you are planning to send the design to a t-shirt printer, they probably won't be able to print that SVG because the software they use almost certainly won't support `<foreignObject>`.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau Yeah,I am planning to print that too,so what will be the solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that SVG does not currently support text areas.

But, as mentioned, if you are only displaying the SVG in a browser, then you can embed HTML with the `<foreignObject>` element.

```html
<svg id="product-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 1280">
  <foreignObject x="200" y="200" width="600" height="600" style="font-size: 40px">
    <body>
      Here is some text with line wrapping. Is this what you wanted?
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes,I got your point,but I want to change the size of text dynamically and get input text from user.Can we resize the #foreignobject size dynamically?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to to do that with JS. And also with CSS if the browser properly supports SVG2.